# Pandas - Combine Excel Rows on ID

Tags: python, excel, pandas

I have a dataframe that currently looks like this. I need to combine the two rows on the id.

```
        id   post                                                   date  
0      10-1  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing...  2012-01-28   
1      10-1  Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation...  2012-01-28
```

Expected result is this:

```
        id   post                                                  date  
0      10-1  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing... 2012-01-28
```

What I have tried:

```
1)    df = df.groupby(['id', 'post'])

2)    df = df.groupby(['id', 'post']).first().reset_index();

3)    df = df.groupby('id', 'post').agg({'post: sum'})


4)     df = df.groupby('id')

       df['id'].nunique()

5)     df = df.groupby('id').agg(lambda x: x.tolist())
```

5 has gotten me the closest. When I run that, it removes duplicates, but doesn't aggregate the post column. I am having trouble understanding how to solve this problem. I don't understand how to groupby two things after reading the documentation.

Comment: When you say combine, is it that you want to end up with a list of all individual words in 'post'?

Comment: @enmet02 No, I want to end up with no duplicate values in the id column while maintaining the integrity of the data in the post column.

Comment: What do you want to happen with the values in 'post'?

Comment: Merge if on the same id, @wen provided the correct solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can can past a dict to agg, `key` of the dict is the `column` and `value` is the function you will implement  to that column.

```
df.groupby('id').agg({'post':'sum','date':'first'})
```

Comment: Damn, i was so close. Is the date necessary? Ah yes, it is. I understand.

Comment: @ChasenBettinger i think date is necessary ,in your case we only keep the first one for each group

Comment: Only if you want to retain it, you haven't given an indication of your expected output. If all you want is a series of all unique values in post for each id, then you can even go one easier and use df.groupby('id')['post'].sum(). However, Wen's approach retains the date too which might be wanted.

Comment: It is, I apologize for being ambiguous.

Comment: You can use join if you want to separate the strings with a `', '`